# What is the missing proportionality constant in the magnetic levitation formula?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, unit-conversion, levitation

The formula for [magnetic levitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation) is

$$ B \frac{dB}{dz} = \frac{ \rho g }{\chi} $$

but as always, I have a hard time figuring the units in SI. The left hand side is $\mathrm{T^2 /m}$, while $\chi$ has units of $\mathrm{m^3\,mol^{-1}}$, which makes the right hand side with units of..

$$\mathrm{kg\,m^{-5}\,s^{-2}\,(mol)}$$

Obviously there must be some constant, but I don't know what is it, as all texts use this natural unit system. Help?

**Update:**

using the [permeability of free space as reported by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_of_free_space), which seems to be Tesla-meter per Ampere, leaves the right hand side as

$$\mathrm{kg\,T\,m^{-4}\,s^{-2}\,Ampere\,mol}$$

still far from being recognizable to the left side

Comment: sounds to me like those susceptibility units are somehow messed up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility#Sources_of_confusion_in_published_data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As lurscher mentioned in a comment, you're using the wrong units for magnetic susceptibility. $\chi$ is actually a dimensionless number that is related to the magnetic permeability of a material relative to that of a vacuum. I think you were mixing it up with the [molar magnetic susceptibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility#Mass_susceptibility_and_molar_susceptibility), which is $\chi_\text{mol} = \mathcal{M}\chi/\rho$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is the molar mass of the substance (units of $\mathrm{kg/mol}$) and $\rho$ is the density (units of $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$). $\chi_\text{mol}$ is the thing with units of $\mathrm{m^3/mol}$, but it's $\chi$ that actually appears in the magnetic levitation formula.

With that cleared up, let's look at the equation. The left side, naturally, has units of $\mathrm{T^2/m}$. If you include the magnetic constant on the right side, as Wikipedia (correctly) does, you have

$$\biggl[\mu_0\frac{ \rho g }{\chi}\biggr] = [\mu_0]\frac{ [\rho] [g] }{[\chi]} = \biggl(\frac{\mathrm{T\,m}}{\mathrm{A}}\Biggr)\frac{\mathrm{(kg/m^3)(m/s^2)}}{1} = \frac{\mathrm{T\,kg}}{\mathrm{m\,s^2\,A}}$$

Here I'm using the notation where putting brackets around a quantity designates the units of that quantity. For example, the units of the magnetic constant are $\mathrm{T\,m/A}$, so $[\mu_0] = \mathrm{T\,m/A}$.

Now you can equate the units of the two sides of the equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{T^2}}{\mathrm{m}} = \frac{\mathrm{T\,kg}}{\mathrm{m\,s^2\,A}}$$

which simplifies to

$$\mathrm{T} = \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{s^2\,A}}$$

So if this equivalence is correct, then it shows that the original equation is dimensionally consistent. And if you look on the [Wikipedia page for the Tesla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_%28unit%29), it does indeed give $\mathrm{T} = \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{s^2\,A}}$ as one of the definitions of that unit.

Alternatively, you could check it using a formula involving magnetic field and current, such as $\vec{F} = I\mathrm{d}\vec{l}\times\vec{B}$. The units of this are $\mathrm{N = A\,m\times T}$, and since $\mathrm{N} = \mathrm{kg\,m/s^2}$, you can set $\mathrm{kg\,m/s^2 = A\,m\,T}$ and find exactly that $\mathrm{T} = \frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{s^2\,A}}$. This is a useful trick that keeps you from having to memorize the definitions of all the SI (or other) units.

Comment: ah i see, i blame this doc: http://www-d0.fnal.gov/hardware/cal/lvps_info/engineering/elementmagn.pdf so it seems i just need to multiply this number by density and dividing by molar mass. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is something that took me a long time to wrap my head around as well, but there actually doesn't need to be a constant (depending on the system of measurement). You mention SI, which is definitely a preferred system, but I'm going to bring up [cgs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units) because it brings some of the underlying funny business to the surface (particularly because of the definitions of the  [statcoulomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb)), and at its roots it's not that far from SI.

You break down the units in SI for the LHS and RHS almost correctly, except this formula uses a [dimensionless $\chi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility#Definition_of_volume_susceptibility), so I start with:

$\frac{T^2}{m} = \frac{kg\cdot}{m^2\cdot s^2}$

I'll rewrite this in cgs units. $T$ is instead $gauss$, $m$ is replaced by $cm$, $kg$ becomes $g$, and $s$ is unchanged. So I get:

$\frac{gauss^2}{cm} = \frac{g}{cm^2\cdot s^2}$

[Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_%28unit%29) is a derived unit which, in more "fundamental" units, is $gauss = \frac{g\cdot cm}{statC\cdot s^2}$. I'm still not actually comfortable trying to explain all the intricacies of the [statcoulomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb) (statC); you'll have to look into that a bit more yourself I'm afraid. It ends up being a unit of charge, but comes with a lot of other implications. In any case, putting in that definition of $gauss$ gives:

$\frac{g^2\cdot cm}{statC^2\cdot s^4} = \frac{g}{cm^2\cdot s^2}$

Or, rearranging and simplifying a bit,

$statC = \frac{g^{1/2}\cdot cm^{3/2}}{s}$

That's actually the definition of the statC, so the equation is dimensionally consistent.

As far as I know the Coulomb from SI doesn't behave at all this way, and I don't have a good way of showing dimensional consistency in SI, but I'd be very interested if someone else did.

Answer (score 0):

$\mu_0$ is missing on the right hand side, and in fact $\chi$ is dimensionless, it is just the ratio between $M$ and $H$. So

$$B \frac{dB}{dz} = \mu_0 \frac{ \rho g }{\chi}$$

The reason:

- the unit of $B^2/\mu_0$ is energy-density ($J/m^3$)
- the unit of $[\rho g]$ is ($N/m^3$)
- as $J=Nm$ everything is fine